# Where is my code error in Yii CDbCriteria?

Tags: php, yii

When i use this code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('paid'=>0, 'confirmed'=>0));
$criteria->addCondition('UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > (date + users.limited_pay_time * 3600)');
$orders = Orders::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

return this error.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.limited_pay_time' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `orders` `t` WHERE (paid=:ycp0 AND confirmed=:ycp1) AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > (date + users.limited_pay_time * 3600))
```

Comment: Does your database have a table called `users`, with a field called `limited_pay_time`?

Comment: on 2nd line add this `$criteria->with('users');`. Just a BIG guess. Assuming `users` is a relation defined in `Orders` Model

Comment: exactly,Yes, it does.

Comment: You talking about the relation or the table/column(which @Nanne asked for) ? And mention us with `@` when you comment. :)

Comment: I added $criteria->with = array('user'); , but it returned this http://s6.picofile.com/file/8252202426/error.png

Comment: Has my question  an answer?

Comment: Error says 'confirmed' column is ambiguos. You need to append proper prefix on your conditions: 't.field' for 'orders' fields and 'users.field' for 'users' fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SQL that is send to the server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` `t` 
WHERE 
(paid=:ycp0 AND confirmed=:ycp1) 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > (date + users.limited_pay_time * 3600))
```

You are only selecting from orders, not from users, so you cannot use the `users.*` fields, as they are not queried!

What you want is to join on your `users` table first, so you actually get that table returned. I'm no expert on Yii, but it shouldn't be to hard to add a join with those `CDbCriteria` you have. See  for instance:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#join-detail